# Snowflake - Update not working with temporary table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi guys i have the following problem, i create a temporary table that loads a couple of rows with different primary keys.

The next 4 columns are the combine pk, all the values in id3 are equal to ' '.

```
ID1         ID2    ID3  ID4
41019279777 808448      2
41024467159 795706      1
41024467159 808448      2
41024467159 821818      3
41027883563 795889      1
41027883563 808448      2
41027883563 821818      3
41600609257 808448      1
41600609257 821818      2
```

The problem is that when i use this temporary table as a query to update another column from another table, only updates certain rows and others don't, UPDATE query is like this:

```
UPDATE DB.SCHEMA.TABLE1 t1
    SET 
        t1.col5 = 1
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
          id1, id3, id2, id4
         FROM 
          NEW_DB.NEW_SCHEMA.TEMPORARY_TABLE
         GROUP BY
          id1, id3, id2, id4) t2
    WHERE
        COALESCE(t1.id1,0) = COALESCE(t2.id1,0)
        AND COALESCE(t1.id3,'') = COALESCE(t2.id3,'')
        AND COALESCE(t1.id2,0) = COALESCE(t2.id2,0)
        AND COALESCE(t1.id4,0) = COALESCE(t2.id4,0);
```

And the thing is when i use the same update query but with a SELECT statment, the join works and the 4 rows are generated (4 rows because in TABLE1 are only 4 of the 9 rows that the temporary table returns)

```
SELECT t1.id1, t1.id2, t1.id3, t1.d4, t2.id1_temp, t2.id2_temp, t2.id3_temp, t2.id4_temp, t1.col5
FROM DB.SCHEMA.TABLE1 t1
JOIN (
  SELECT 
    id1_temp, id3_temp, id2_temp, id4_temp
  FROM 
    NEW_DB.NEW_SCHEMA.TEMPORARY_TABLE
  GROUP BY id1_temp, id3_temp, id2_temp, id4_temp) t2
WHERE
  t1.id1 IN (41600609257,41024467159,41027883563,41019279777) --> filtering only id1 i need to check
  AND COALESCE(t1.id1,0) = COALESCE(t2.id1,0)
  AND COALESCE(t1.id3,'') = COALESCE(t2.id3,'')
  AND COALESCE(t1.id2,0) = COALESCE(t2.id2,0)
  AND COALESCE(t1.id4,0) = COALESCE(t2.id4,0);
```

The result gives me

```
ID1         ID2    ID3  ID4 ID1_TEMP    ID2_TEMP    ID3_TEMP    ID4_TEMP    COL5
41027883563 821818      3   41027883563 821818                  3           null
41024467159 821818      3   41024467159 821818                  3           null
41600609257 821818      2   41600609257 821818                  2           null
41019279777 808448      2   41019279777 808448                  2           null
```

So the join is done in the update i think but not update has been done to this rows. Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: Why is the first query `id1, id3, id2, id4` and the second one `id1_temp, id3_temp, id2_temp, id4_temp`? Is the table being `temp` relevant? Does this work if it's not a `temp` table? (We need more details to replicate)

Comment: @FelipeHoffa hi Felipe, Table1 is the final table that i need to update with the value 1 on column col5 when the idX columns, part of the pk, joins with Table2 that is a temporary table, as i show, the temp table have 4 rows that joins with 4 of the rows of Table1, and it works, works for others rows, but particularly with this 4 (and others), doesnt